# Scraping with Rvest: Links are not picked up with html_attr('href')

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape an archive of job postings in Denmark with some specific filters on the website. When I try to scrape all of the headings and their links, I can get the headings but not the links. I have tried to different selectors, but nothing picks up the links. The CSS selector ".jix_job_archived > a b , #result_list_box strong" picks up all headings. 
For the site provided the first link should be: https://www.jobindex.dk/c?t=r8830962&ctx=w

I have included a picture of the website where I want to scrape the "href" marked in the right of the screen.

[image]

```
library(rvest)
library(tibble)
    sel<- ".jix_job_archived > a b , #result_list_box strong" 
    jobindex <- "https://www.jobindex.dk/jobsoegning/kontor/offentlig?jobage=archive&maxdate=20200330&mindate=19901230"

    tbl <- tibble(text = pg 
    %>% html_nodes(css = sel) %>% 
    html_text(), link = pg %>% html_nodes(css = sel) %>% html_attr('href'))
    view(tbl)

**# A tibble: 20 x 2
   text                                                                                                link 
   <chr>                                                                                               <chr>
 1 Administrativ medarbejder/sekretær til stabsfunktion                                                NA   
 2 Meeqqeriviup_igaffia_inuussutissanut_ikiortimik_pissarsiorpoq                                       NA   **
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link is outside the `<strong>` tag. So, if you supply `html_nodes` with selector `".jix_job_archived > a b , #result_list_box strong"`, no link will be picked-up.

This might help.

```
library(rvest)
library(tibble)

jobindex <- "https://www.jobindex.dk/jobsoegning/kontor/offentlig?jobage=archive&maxdate=20200330&mindate=19901230"

jobnodes <- jobindex %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_nodes(".jobsearch-result") 

text <- jobnodes %>% html_text %>% trimws() %>% sub("(.*?)\\n.*","\\1",.)
link1 <- jobnodes %>% html_node("a") %>% html_attr("data-click")
link2 <- jobnodes %>% html_node("a") %>% html_attr("href")

tbl <- tibble(text = text, link1 = link1,  link2 = link2)
```

**Output**

```
tbl

# # A tibble: 20 x 3
#    text                                              link1             link2                                                              
#    <chr>                                             <chr>             <chr>                                                              
#  1 Administrativ medarbejder/sekretær til stabsfunk… /c?t=r8830962&ct… http://www.profiljob.dk/resultat/administrativ-medarbejdersekretae…
#  2 Meeqqeriviup_igaffia_inuussutissanut_ikiortimik_… /c?t=r8831043&ct… https://www.qeqqata.gl/Ledig_stillinger/2020/04/Meeqqeriviup_igaff…
#  3 Borgerrådgiver                                    /c?t=r8828448&ct… https://favrskov.dk/sites/default/files/borgerraadgiver_enkeltside…
#  4 Kombineret stilling som forebyggelseskonsulent o… /c?t=r8828382&ct… https://www.qeqqata.gl/Ledig_stillinger/2020/04/Forebyggelseskonsu…
#  5 Stilling som koordinerende sagsbehandler for ung… /c?t=h972855&ctx… http://www.solrod.dk/                                              
#  6 Sagsbehandler til jobafklarings- og ressourcefor… /c?t=h972838&ctx… http://www.solrod.dk/                                              
#  7 2-3 skolesekretærer søges til landsbyordningerne… /c?t=r8827011&ct… https://www.skolejobs.dk/stilling/landsbyordningerne-i-odder-kommu…
#  8 Overassistent i Vejledning ved Majoriaq i Sisimi… /c?t=r8825989&ct… https://www.qeqqata.gl/Ledig_stillinger/2020/03/Overassistent_vejl…
#  9 Generalist                                        /c?t=r8824808&ct… https://naalakkersuisut.emply.net/recruitment/vacancyAd.aspx?publi…
# 10 Administrativ medarbejder til Små og mellemstore… /c?t=h972425&ctx… https://www.sktst.dk/                                              
# 11 Akademiker til Stab og Udviklingsopgaver          /c?t=r8824111&ct… https://www.ofir.dk/resultat/akademiker-til-stab-og-udviklingsopga…
# 12 2 dygtige og motiverede administrative medarbejd… /c?t=h972318&ctx… https://phabsalon.dk/                                              
# 13 Tjenestefordeler – Trafikstyring Øst              /c?t=h972077&ctx… http://www.banedanmark.dk/                                         
# 14 Planlægningskonsulent søges til Psykiatrien       /c?t=r8821953&ct… https://rm.emply.net/recruitment/vacancyAd.aspx?publishingId=a81f5…
# 15 Fundraiser                                        /c?t=r8821594&ct… https://www.jobindex.dk/jobannonce/jobnet/8821594                  
# 16 Projektleder i Borgmesterens Afdeling som vil ta… /c?t=r8820419&ct… https://www.jobindex.dk/jobannonce/jobnet/8820419                  
# 17 Administrativ medarbejder til Borger- og retssik… /c?t=h971668&ctx… https://candidate.hr-manager.net/ApplicationInit.aspx?cid=5001&Pro…
# 18 Kollega til Myndighed Handicap- og psykiatriafde… /c?t=r8818554&ct… https://www.ofir.dk/resultat/kollega-til-myndighed-handicap-og-psy…
# 19 Energiplanlægger søges til By, Kultur og Miljøse… /c?t=r8818534&ct… https://www.ofir.dk/resultat/energiplanlaegger-soeges-til-by-kultu…
# 20 Akademisk medarbejder til Regionspsykiatrien Ran… /c?t=r8819996&ct… https://www.ofir.dk/resultat/akademisk-medarbejder-til-regionspsyk…
```

Comment: The links are wrong. As you can see on the picture, I want to receive the href for the article. It should look something like https://www.jobindex.dk/c?t=r8830962&ctx=w or just /c?t=r8830962&ctx=w

Comment: that is not wrong. href is not always something like jobindex.dk*****. You can look into page source, for "Meeqqeriviup_igaffia_inuussutissanut_ikiortimik_pissarsiorpoq", that is  `<a data-click="/c?t=r8831043&amp;ctx=w" href="https://www.qeqqata.gl/Ledig_stillinger/2020/04/Meeqqeriviup_igaffia_inuussutissanut_ikiortimik_pissarsiorpoq?sc_lang=da" rel="noopener" target="_blank">
        <strong>Meeqqeriviup_igaffia_inuussutissanut_ikiortimik_pissarsiorpoq</strong>
    </a>`

Comment: answer updated. I picked up `data-click` (insted of `href`) to match your need.

Comment: Though I only get 14 out of 20. Is there a way around that. If you look at "Stilling som koordinerende sagsbehandler for unge i ressourceforløb" as example is not included.

Comment: Upps! look like there's are 2 type of job posting (might be reguler and paid). You can notice that any paid jobs posting (those with "Quick apply" button)  are  not be picked up, because they use different css selector.